# Interior of $S^n_+$ (semi definite positive matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I have read that the interior of $S^n_+$ in $S^n$ (real symmetric matrices of size $n\times n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}^*)$ is $S^n_{++}$. I am trying to prove it.

I have that there is no open set bigger than $S^n_{++}$ contained in $S^n_{+}$: if there were such a set, call it $V$, then taking $A \in V \setminus S^n_{++}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ small enough, $A - \epsilon I_n$ would be in $V$ (by openness), hence in $S^n_{+}$ but not in $S^n_{++}$.

But $0$ being an eigenvalue of $A$, $-\epsilon$ would be an eigenvalue of $A - \epsilon I_n$, absurd because this matrix is in $S^n_{+}$ hence has all eigenvalues $\geq 0$.

However I am struggling to prove that $S^n_{++}$ is open. I am tempted to say that $A\mapsto Sp(A)$ is continuous, because $A \mapsto \chi_A$ is continuous (the coefficients of $\chi_A$ are polynomials in coefficents of $A$) and roots of polynomials are continuous wrt the coefficents of the polynomial.

However i have also read that the interior of $S^n_{+}$ in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is empty, and I don't see what goes wrong in my proof in this case, so I guess there is a mistake. Can someone pinpoint it and provide a correct proof, hopefully in the same spirit?

Comment: For any $A \in S^n_+$ and nonsymmetric matrix $B \in \mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb R)$, $A + \epsilon B$ is a nonsymmetric matrix in $\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb R)$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon > 0$, so every neighborhood of $A$ in $\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb R)$ contains elements not in $S^n_+$, that is, $A$ is not in the interior of $S^n_+$ in $\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb R)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument correctly allows us to deduce that $S^{n}_{++}$ is an open set relative to the set of symmetric matrices.  Another argument that works is to note that $A \mapsto \det(A)$ is continuous.

Of course, $S^n_{++}$ is not open relative to the larger space $\mathcal M_n$.  In particular, the symmetric matrices form a proper subspace of $\mathcal M_n$, and it follows that symmetric matrices has an empty interior within $\mathcal M_n$, as does any subset of the symmetric matrices.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is rather: "Where does my reasoning (apparently correct in $S^n$ fail when applied in $M_n$?"

Comment: Oh,  that's easy: eigenvalues alone are insufficient to determine that a matrix is symmetric.  By the usual definition, positive semidefinite matrices are necessarily symmetric.  Your argument could be directly applied to $\mathcal M_n$ show, for instance, that the set of matrices whose eigenvalues all have positive real part is open.

Comment: Oh yes, I was too focused on eigenvalues. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, after reading I still failed to find out what is the interior of the definite positive matrix with a trace of no more than 1. Could you help me? Many thanks!

Comment: @ForestLiu You should post a question about that, and be careful about what exactly you mean by the "interior" in this context. If you mean the interior relative to the subspace topology on the set of symmetric matrices, then the interior should be the set of positive definite matrices with trace strictly less than $1$.