# Question about Interior of $S^n_+$ (semi definite positive matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

I read this link [Interior of $S^n_+$ (semi definite positive matrices)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918530/interior-of-sn-semi-definite-positive-matrices) and I have a question about What would be the relative interior of $S^n_+$ I prove that $S^n_+$ it's a is a closed pointed convex cone in $S^n$ so I think that the hull affine is itself, so the relative interior of $S^n_+$ would be the same as the interior. Is my statement correct? And if yes, how do I justify that the affine capsule of S_n+ is the same

Comment: If a subset of a normed space has a non-empty interior, then it agrees with the relative interior; the affine hull of any non-trivial ball is the entire space, hence the same is true for any set that contains one. Note that $S_+^n$ also exists in the space of $n \times n$ matrices, in which $S_+^n$ has no interior (but a relative interior), but in $S^n$, the relative interior is just the interior.

Comment: @TheoBendit I see, so if I want to calculate the relative interior in the $nxn$ matrices, what would be the affine of $S_n^+$, would it be $S_n^+$ So could I use the same prove right?

Comment: It would be $S_n$ (which I assume you meant to write). The fact that $S_n$ is an affine (linear, in fact) subspace of the $n \times n$ matrices that contains $S_n^+$, and $S_n^+$ has non-empty interior with respect to the subspace topology, tells us that $S_n$ is the affine hull of $S_n^+$.

Comment: @TheoBendit I see, thank you very much.